# Beth fixed points and transitive models of ZFC minus Replacement

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

Let ZC denote ZFC without the axiom schema of replacement.  Is there a minimal subset of the replacement schema that can be added to ZC to guarantee that for all models of the resulting theory of the form $V_\alpha$ for some ordinal $\alpha$, the ordinal $\alpha$ must be a beth fixed point (or, equivalently, $\alpha = |V_\alpha|$)?

For instance, for any model of ZFC of the form  $V_\alpha$, the ordinal $\alpha$ must be a worldly cardinal, a beth fixed point, and more. (See [If there is a "worldly ordinal," then must there be a worldly cardinal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3804513/if-there-is-a-worldly-ordinal-then-must-there-be-a-worldly-cardinal/3804525?noredirect=1#comment7841614_3804525.))) On the other hand, $V_{\alpha}$ is a model of ZC for any limit ordinal $\alpha > \omega$.  I'm looking for the weakest subschema of replacement that guarantees that $\alpha$ must be a beth fixed point for any model $V_\alpha$ of ZC plus that schema.  Maybe such a subschema would have to include all of replacement?

Note that adding to ZC the axiom of "transfinite recursion on ordinals" is not enough, since $V_{\aleph_1}$ is a model for that theory, by a theorem in http://jdh.hamkins.org/transfinite-recursion-as-a-fundamental-principle-in-set-theory/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Claim.** The following are equivalent for a limit ordinal $\alpha$ :

1. $\alpha$ is a beth-fixed point.
2. $V_\alpha$ thinks every set is equipotent with an ordinal.

For $1\to 2$, it suffices to show that for every $\beta<\alpha$, $V_\alpha$ thinks $V_\beta$ is equipotent with an ordinal. (This is because every set in $V_\alpha$ is a subset of some $V_\beta$, $\beta<\alpha$.) Let $f:V_\beta\to\beth_\beta$ be a bijection. Then $f$ is a subset of $V_\beta\times \beth_\beta$, which is a member of $V_\alpha$. Since $V_\alpha$ is closed under Cartesian products and power sets, $f\in V_\alpha$.

For $2\to 1$, observe that the assumption implies $|V_\beta|\in V_\alpha$ for every $\beta<\alpha$, so $\beth_\beta<\alpha$ for all $\beta<\alpha$, which means $\alpha$ is a $\beth$-fixed point.

---

I finally prove that the above characterization is equivalent to the validity of $\Sigma_1$-replacement over $V_\alpha$:

**Claim.** If $\alpha$ is a beth-fixed point, then $V_\alpha$ satisfies $\Sigma_1$-Replacement.

The main ingredient is the following version of Levy reflection principle (which is provable by the same proof of usual Levy reflection principle $H_\kappa\prec_{\Sigma_1} V$)

> **Theorem.** Let $\lambda<\kappa$ be cardinals and $\lambda$ be regular. Then $H_\lambda\prec_{\Sigma_1} V_\kappa$.

Moreover, it is known that $H_\lambda$ is a model of ZFC without Power set if $\lambda$ is regular.
Now let $F$ be a $\Sigma_1$-class function over $V_\alpha$ with a parameter $p$. Take $x\in V_\alpha$. Choose $\xi<\alpha$ such that $p,x\in V_\xi$. Since $\alpha$ is a beth-fixed point, $\lambda:=|V_\xi|^+<\alpha$. We can see that $V_\xi\subseteq H_\lambda\subseteq V_\alpha$.

Observe that $F$ is absolute between $V_\alpha$ and $H_\lambda$. Moreover, $H_\lambda$ satisfies Replacement for $F$. Let $H_\lambda\models F^"[x]=y$ for $y\in H_\lambda$. Since the formula
$$[\forall v\in y\exists u\in x (F(u)=v)]\land [\forall u\in x\exists v\in y (F(u)=v)]$$
is $\Sigma_1$-formula, it also holds over $V_\alpha$. This shows $y$ witnesses the instance of replacement for $F$, $x$ and $p$.

Comment: Nice.  Can you express this in terms of some subschema of replacement?

Comment: @JesseElliott I do not know, but the statement "every set is equipotent with an ordinal" is a consequence of replacement for $\Sigma_1$-formulas over ZC.

Comment: Inspecting the proof of Theorem 2.12 of Jech gives a more specific instance of Replacement that implies the assertion "every set is equipotent with an ordinal," but I do not know it is actually equivalent to that.

Comment: I suppose this is equivalent to the question of whether $V_\alpha$ is a model of ZC plus $\Sigma_1$-replacement for every beth fixed point $\alpha$.

Comment: @JesseElliott I added the proof that $V_\alpha$ satisfies $\Sigma_1$-replacement if $\alpha$ is a beth fixed point. I hope it is satisfactory to you.

Comment: Thank you!  I think it's a very nice result.

Comment: I'm confused now because it seems that $V_\alpha$ is a model of KP (Kripke-Platek Set Theory) with Infinity (and Power Set) if and only if $\alpha$ is a beth fixed point, and yet that theory doesn't prove Replacement for $\Sigma_1$-formulas, or even that $V_{\omega+\omega}$ exists:    See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AKripke-Platek_set_theory   Does this mean we need the full axiom of separation for your argument to go through?

Comment: @JesseElliott Yes and no. My proof heavily relies on the fact that $V_\alpha$ is closed under subsets of an element, so we may say we use second-order separation. On the other hand, $\mathsf{KP}$ proves replacement for $\Sigma_1$-formulas. (See Theorem 1.4.6 of *Admissible sets and structures* by Barwise.)

Comment: It would be better to say that our proof heavily relies on the structure of $V_\alpha$.

Comment: Oh, then KP plus Power Set doesn't prove that $V_{\omega+\omega}$ exists because $x \in V_{\omega+\omega}$ isn't $\Sigma_1$, not because it doesn't prove replacement for $\Sigma_1$-formulas.  I think I understand now.

Comment: If one wants an extension of KP that proves that $V_\alpha$ exists for all $\alpha$ less than the first beth fixed point, does one need replacement for $\Sigma_2$-formulas, or something like that?

Comment: @JesseElliott I think $\Sigma_2$-replacement suffices, and it proves $V_\alpha$ exists for all $\alpha$, in fact.

Comment: Oh dear, then the models $V_\alpha$ of $\Sigma_2$-replacement don't include all such for $\alpha$ a beth fixed point.  Which $V_\alpha$'s are models of $\Sigma_2$-replacement?  That would be just for strongly inaccessible $\alpha$? Sorry for all the follow-up questions.

Comment: @JesseElliott No, there is no reason to think $V_\alpha$ includes all beth-fixed points. For example, every cumulative hierarchy at a worldly (or inaccessible) cardinal satisfies replacement, but they do not contain all beth-fixed points.

Comment: Of course, if $V_\alpha$ models $\Sigma_2$-replacement then $\alpha$ satisfies stronger closure properties (e.g., $\alpha$ is closed under beth-fixed point operator, which sends an ordinal $\xi$ to a $\xi$-th beth-fixed point.)

Comment: Does $\Sigma_2$-replacement imply the existence of a beth-fixed point (or a even a proper class of them)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112758/discussion-between-jesse-elliott-and-hanul-jeon).

Comment: @JesseElliott I think the lastest question is a bit different question from the initial one, so it would be better to ask as a separate question.